# When using ipvlan l3, I can't filter packets with iptables

Tags: networking, iptables, virtual-machine, tc

My general intention is to run hypervisor instances in separate network namespaces. I have something that looks promising, but as I dug into trying to make things work with iptables, I found some strange behavior that's preventing me from doing normal stateful firewall things.

Set up the host environment a bit like this:

```
# Set up packet forwarding on physical interface.
sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.enp0s31f6.forwarding=1

# Set up ipvlan in namespace
ip netns add vm0
ip link add ipvlan0 link enp0s31f6 type ipvlan mode l3
ip link set dev ipvlan0 netns vm0
ip netns exec vm0 ip link set ipvlan0 up
ip netns exec vm0 ip link set lo up
# note: physical interface has addr 2a01:4f9:2b:35a::2/64
ip netns exec vm0 ip addr add dev ipvlan0 2a01:4f9:2b:35a::3/128

# Set up tap
ip netns exec vm0 ip tuntap add dev tap0 mode tap user fdr
# set MAC just for convenience to keep link local addresses the same between attempts
ip netns exec vm0 ip link set address ca:9d:46:13:9b:64 dev tap0
ip netns exec vm0 ip link set dev tap0 up
```

Start up a virtual machine in vm0 connected to the tap. Run these to set up its address and routes:

```
export HOST_TAP_LLADDR=fe80::c89d:46ff:fe13:9b64
sudo ip addr add 2a01:4f9:2b:35a::3/128 dev ens4
sudo ip link set ens4 up
sudo ip route add default via $HOST_TAP_LLADDR dev ens4
```

Okay, now if you start pinging from the VM and attach `tcpdump -lenvi tap0` you can watch ICMP on `tap0`, but it doesn't go anywhere beyond, which is expected, since within the namespace we haven't done anything to get traffic from `tap0` to `ipvlan0`

```
# tcpdump -lenvi tap0
tcpdump: listening on tap0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), snapshot length 262144 bytes
20:32:02.332080 IP6 (flowlabel 0x60b7e, hlim 64, next-header ICMPv6 (58) payload length: 64) 2a01:4f9:2b:35a::3 > 2a00:1450:400f:80c::200e: [icmp6 sum ok] ICMP6, echo request, id 2, seq 527
20:32:03.356084 IP6 (flowlabel 0x60b7e, hlim 64, next-header ICMPv6 (58) payload length: 64) 2a01:4f9:2b:35a::3 > 2a00:1450:400f:80c::200e: [icmp6 sum ok] ICMP6, echo request, id 2, seq 528
20:32:04.380079 IP6 (flowlabel 0x60b7e, hlim 64, next-header ICMPv6 (58) payload length: 64) 2a01:4f9:2b:35a::3 > 2a00:1450:400f:80c::200e: [icmp6 sum ok] ICMP6, echo request, id 2, seq 529
20:32:05.404096 IP6 (flowlabel 0x60b7e, hlim 64, next-header ICMPv6 (58) payload length: 64) 2a01:4f9:2b:35a::3 > 2a00:1450:400f:80c::200e: [icmp6 sum ok] ICMP6, echo request, id 2, seq 530
^C
```

```
#  tcpdump -lenvi ipvlan0
tcpdump: listening on ipvlan0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), snapshot length 262144 bytes
<nothing>
^C
```

Okay, so lets do something about that. Taking packets from `tap0` and putting them into `ipvlan0` is easier, you can use a route:

```
# Note: I can't seem to get routing to work by enabling forwarding on
# individual interfaces in the namespace, which is weird.
sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.all.forwarding=1
ip route add default via fe80::1 dev ipvlan0 proto static
```

We can confirm this with tcpdump: we'll see `tap0` only send ICMP, and `ipvlan0` both send those packets and receive ICMP responses:

```
root@Ubuntu-2204-jammy-amd64-base ~ #  tcpdump -lenvi ipvlan0
tcpdump: listening on ipvlan0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), snapshot length 262144 bytes
20:42:08.542989 4c:52:62:0e:05:d3 > 4c:52:62:0e:05:d3, ethertype IPv6 (0x86dd), length 118: (flowlabel 0x60b7e, hlim 63, next-header ICMPv6 (58) payload length: 64) 2a01:4f9:2b:35a::3 > 2a00:1450:400f:80c::200e: [icmp6 sum ok] ICMP6, echo request, id 2, seq 1119
20:42:08.549416 d0:07:ca:8d:19:31 > 4c:52:62:0e:05:d3, ethertype IPv6 (0x86dd), length 118: (flowlabel 0x60b7e, hlim 119, next-header ICMPv6 (58) payload length: 64) 2a00:1450:400f:80c::200e > 2a01:4f9:2b:35a::3: [icmp6 sum ok] ICMP6, echo reply, id 2, seq 1119
20:42:09.567009 4c:52:62:0e:05:d3 > 4c:52:62:0e:05:d3, ethertype IPv6 (0x86dd), length 118: (flowlabel 0x60b7e, hlim 63, next-header ICMPv6 (58) payload length: 64) 2a01:4f9:2b:35a::3 > 2a00:1450:400f:80c::200e: [icmp6 sum ok] ICMP6, echo request, id 2, seq 1120
20:42:09.573468 d0:07:ca:8d:19:31 > 4c:52:62:0e:05:d3, ethertype IPv6 (0x86dd), length 118: (flowlabel 0x60b7e, hlim 119, next-header ICMPv6 (58) payload length: 64) 2a00:1450:400f:80c::200e > 2a01:4f9:2b:35a::3: [icmp6 sum ok] ICMP6, echo reply, id 2, seq 1120
20:42:10.590995 4c:52:62:0e:05:d3 > 4c:52:62:0e:05:d3, ethertype IPv6 (0x86dd), length 118: (flowlabel 0x60b7e, hlim 63, next-header ICMPv6 (58) payload length: 64) 2a01:4f9:2b:35a::3 > 2a00:1450:400f:80c::200e: [icmp6 sum ok] ICMP6, echo request, id 2, seq 1121
20:42:10.597439 d0:07:ca:8d:19:31 > 4c:52:62:0e:05:d3, ethertype IPv6 (0x86dd), length 118: (flowlabel 0x60b7e, hlim 119, next-header ICMPv6 (58) payload length: 64) 2a00:1450:400f:80c::200e > 2a01:4f9:2b:35a::3: [icmp6 sum ok] ICMP6, echo reply, id 2, seq 1121
^C

root@Ubuntu-2204-jammy-amd64-base ~ # tcpdump -lenvi tap0
tcpdump: listening on tap0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), snapshot length 262144 bytes
20:42:14.686993 2e:db:57:5c:90:28 > ca:9d:46:13:9b:64, ethertype IPv6 (0x86dd), length 118: (flowlabel 0x60b7e, hlim 64, next-header ICMPv6 (58) payload length: 64) 2a01:4f9:2b:35a::3 > 2a00:1450:400f:80c::200e: [icmp6 sum ok] ICMP6, echo request, id 2, seq 1125
20:42:15.710995 2e:db:57:5c:90:28 > ca:9d:46:13:9b:64, ethertype IPv6 (0x86dd), length 118: (flowlabel 0x60b7e, hlim 64, next-header ICMPv6 (58) payload length: 64) 2a01:4f9:2b:35a::3 > 2a00:1450:400f:80c::200e: [icmp6 sum ok] ICMP6, echo request, id 2, seq 1126
20:42:16.735027 2e:db:57:5c:90:28 > ca:9d:46:13:9b:64, ethertype IPv6 (0x86dd), length 118: (flowlabel 0x60b7e, hlim 64, next-header ICMPv6 (58) payload length: 64) 2a01:4f9:2b:35a::3 > 2a00:1450:400f:80c::200e: [icmp6 sum ok] ICMP6, echo request, id 2, seq 1127
^C
```

But now we're stuck: how to get packets from `ipvlan0` to `tap0`? I found success with `tc` to mirror the packets, and rewrite their destination MAC address:

```
# Move frames between tap and ipvlan, changing MAC addresses so the
# receiving side knows the frame is for them, and filtering on IP
# addresses in event of oddly addressed traffic coming in or going
# out.
tc qdisc add dev ipvlan0 handle ffff: ingress
export VM_MAC=2e:db:57:5c:90:28
tc filter add dev ipvlan0 parent ffff: protocol ipv6 \
  u32 match ip6 dst 2a01:4f9:2b:35a::3 \
  action skbmod set dmac $VM_MAC \
  action mirred egress redirect dev tap0
```

Finally, we're rewarded with `ping` working and we can review tcpdump on `tap0`:

```
tcpdump -lenvi tap0
tcpdump: listening on tap0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), snapshot length 262144 bytes
20:46:09.471859 2e:db:57:5c:90:28 > ca:9d:46:13:9b:64, ethertype IPv6 (0x86dd), length 118: (flowlabel 0x60b7e, hlim 64, next-header ICMPv6 (58) payload length: 64) 2a01:4f9:2b:35a::3 > 2a00:1450:400f:80c::200e: [icmp6 sum ok] ICMP6, echo request, id 3, seq 5
20:46:09.478344 d0:07:ca:8d:19:31 > 2e:db:57:5c:90:28, ethertype IPv6 (0x86dd), length 118: (flowlabel 0x60b7e, hlim 119, next-header ICMPv6 (58) payload length: 64) 2a00:1450:400f:80c::200e > 2a01:4f9:2b:35a::3: [icmp6 sum ok] ICMP6, echo reply, id 3, seq 5
20:46:10.473455 2e:db:57:5c:90:28 > ca:9d:46:13:9b:64, ethertype IPv6 (0x86dd), length 118: (flowlabel 0x60b7e, hlim 64, next-header ICMPv6 (58) payload length: 64) 2a01:4f9:2b:35a::3 > 2a00:1450:400f:80c::200e: [icmp6 sum ok] ICMP6, echo request, id 3, seq 6
20:46:10.479936 d0:07:ca:8d:19:31 > 2e:db:57:5c:90:28, ethertype IPv6 (0x86dd), length 118: (flowlabel 0x60b7e, hlim 119, next-header ICMPv6 (58) payload length: 64) 2a00:1450:400f:80c::200e > 2a01:4f9:2b:35a::3: [icmp6 sum ok] ICMP6, echo reply, id 3, seq 6
```

As long as we've brought in `tc`, we can arguably simplify the entire thing by getting rid of routing and doing the same thing in the other direction, from `tap0` to `ipvlan0`:

```
# Undo routing stuff
sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.all.forwarding=0
ip route del default via fe80::1 dev ipvlan0

# Use tc much the same, but in reverse:
tc qdisc add dev tap0 handle ffff: ingress
# ipvlan shares host MAC with the physical interface
tc filter add dev tap0 parent ffff: protocol ipv6 \
  u32 match ip6 src 2a01:4f9:2b:35a::3 \
  action skbmod set dmac 4c:52:62:0e:05:d3 \
  action mirred egress redirect dev ipvlan0
```

Once again the packets flow:

```
# tcpdump -lenvi tap0
tcpdump: listening on tap0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), snapshot length 262144 bytes
20:52:25.641314 2e:db:57:5c:90:28 > ca:9d:46:13:9b:64, ethertype IPv6 (0x86dd), length 118: (flowlabel 0x60b7e, hlim 64, next-header ICMPv6 (58) payload length: 64) 2a01:4f9:2b:35a::3 > 2a00:1450:400f:80c::200e: [icmp6 sum ok] ICMP6, echo request, id 3, seq 377
20:52:25.647845 d0:07:ca:8d:19:31 > 2e:db:57:5c:90:28, ethertype IPv6 (0x86dd), length 118: (flowlabel 0x60b7e, hlim 119, next-header ICMPv6 (58) payload length: 64) 2a00:1450:400f:80c::200e > 2a01:4f9:2b:35a::3: [icmp6 sum ok] ICMP6, echo reply, id 3, seq 377
^C
```

Now, at this point I thought I had everything working great, only to find that iptables acts very strangely. For example, enable logging:

```
ip6tables -I INPUT 1 -j LOG
ip6tables -I FORWARD 1 -j LOG
ip6tables -I OUTPUT 1 -j LOG
```

If I do a ping directly from the host namespace, I get an `OUT` record and then an `IN` records as expected:

```
Feb 09 20:54:37 Ubuntu-2204-jammy-amd64-base kernel: IN= OUT=enp0s31f6 SRC=2a01:04f9:002b:035a:0000:0000:0000:0002 DST=2a00:1450:400f:080c:0000:0000:0000:200e LEN=104 TC=0 HOPLIMIT=64 FLOWLBL=471262 PROTO=ICMPv6 TYPE=128 CODE=0 ID=3 SEQ=1 
Feb 09 20:54:37 Ubuntu-2204-jammy-amd64-base kernel: IN=enp0s31f6 OUT= MAC=4c:52:62:0e:05:d3:d0:07:ca:8d:19:31:86:dd SRC=2a00:1450:400f:080c:0000:0000:0000:200e DST=2a01:04f9:002b:035a:0000:0000:0000:0002 LEN=104 TC=0 HOPLIMIT=60 FLOWLBL=471262 PROTO=ICMPv6 TYPE=129 CODE=0 ID=3 SEQ=1
```

But, even though traffic is flowing, I can only get an `OUT` record for my VM traffic, even though we know from tcpdump that it is receiving packets as well and pinging successfully:

```
Feb 09 20:58:53 Ubuntu-2204-jammy-amd64-base kernel: IN= OUT=enp0s31f6 SRC=2a01:04f9:002b:035a:0000:0000:0000:0003 DST=2a00:1450:400f:080c:0000:0000:0000:200e LEN=104 TC=0 HOPLIMIT=64 FLOWLBL=396158 PROTO=ICMPv6 TYPE=128 CODE=0 ID=3 SEQ=764 
Feb 09 20:58:54 Ubuntu-2204-jammy-amd64-base kernel: IN= OUT=enp0s31f6 SRC=2a01:04f9:002b:035a:0000:0000:0000:0003 DST=2a00:1450:400f:080c:0000:0000:0000:200e LEN=104 TC=0 HOPLIMIT=64 FLOWLBL=396158 PROTO=ICMPv6 TYPE=128 CODE=0 ID=3 SEQ=765 
Feb 09 20:58:55 Ubuntu-2204-jammy-amd64-base kernel: IN= OUT=enp0s31f6 SRC=2a01:04f9:002b:035a:0000:0000:0000:0003 DST=2a00:1450:400f:080c:0000:0000:0000:200e LEN=104 TC=0 HOPLIMIT=64 FLOWLBL=396158 PROTO=ICMPv6 TYPE=128 CODE=0 ID=3 SEQ=766
```

Furthermore, my attempts to get the namespace `vm0` to log anything via iptables have not worked, only the host produces this log, and it is missing `IN` entries. This means my ability to do stateful firewalling seems to not exist.

So, what going on? Am I barking up the wrong tree?

Comment: Never used l3 mode, but check this: https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/tree/Documentation/networking/ipvlan.rst?h=v6.1#n85

Comment: I did try out l3s, but the thing that I couldn't figure out was how to get the traffic back to the interface, e.g. tcpdump on the ipvlan was empty. Normally once I set the address it starts getting traffic. I actually do have something that works now with some old-school veths and is all IP/routing based, but it would be nice to have something more concise.

Comment: l3s mode? https://docs.kernel.org/networking/ipvlan.html